# Securing a .NET core API using a react frontend

Tags: .net-core, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

Currently I have a react frontend that authenticates users using msal.js (Azure AD B2C). The backend API is built with .NET Core and currently accessible to anyone.

I would like to secure the API so that only a user authenticated on the frontend can access the API.

Is there any documentation/sample apps on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

- *Yes, you can secure the application. using **React authenticate API** which naturally handles the authentication which was imported by other parts of the app.*
- *Here is the [**example**](https://auth0.com/blog/developing-web-apps-with-asp-dot-net-core-2-dot-0-and-react-part-2/) Tutorial of creating a react App with Authentication.*
- *The Authentication React App is based on the **NPM**.*
- *here is the command that used for creating React APP auth.*

```bash
create-react-app react-auth0
```

- *Also, you can go through the [**So**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66129446) thread which has related discussions.*